# How to migrate ROS PKG for Kuka youbot from Hydro to Kinetic

Tags: ros, driver, ros-hydro, ros-kinetic, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

For Kuka youbot, I am trying to install (by source) its Hydro driver (youbot_driver) and ROS wrapper (youbot_driver_ros_interface) in ROS Kinetic. but I receive this error as follows.

```
ResourceNotFound: youbot_description

ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros

ROS path [1]=/home/alireza/catkin_ws/src

ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

Dose anyone know how to solve this issue?

There are the links:

[youbot driver](git clone http://github.com/youbot/youbot_driver.git -b hydro-devel)

[youbot ros wapper](git clone http://github.com/youbot/youbot_driver_ros_interface.git -b hydro-devel)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297751/how-to-migrate-ros-pkg-for-kuka-youbot-from-hydro-to-kinetic/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2018-07-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-17**:
Can you please provide a link to the package that you're referring to?

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2018-07-18**:
did you try sourcing after building the package?

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2018-07-18**:
Yes, I did

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2018-07-18**:
@jayess I have provided the links

**Comment by [arafat](https://answers.ros.org/users/40874/arafat/) on 2019-04-14**:
did it work for you sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should try cloning the [youbot_description](https://github.com/youbot/youbot_description) package into your workspace as well.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2018-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0